# Snakemake hangs after DAG is completed for a large workflow

Tags: snakemake

I have a relatively large workflow as a result of combination of two wildcards. The first wildcard has 293 values. The second wildcard has 62 values. If I run the workflow for one of the values for the second wildcard it runs fine. However, if I run with all the values for the second wildcard, the workflow computes the DAG and then just hangs. If I run with --debug-dag I see the output stops after:

```
    wildcards: 
file None:
    Producer found, hence exceptions are ignored.
```

And then nothing happens, it just freezes.
For now I was able to solve this by running with a bash for loop for each of the 62 values of the second wildcard. I also tried --batch flag. The DAG computation was faster but still the command line froze after DAG computation.
The problem is, I now need to aggregate over the 62 values of the second wildcard to produce the final output and I can't run the workflow.

Any ideas on how to get this working?

Thank you,

Ilya.

Comment: Is there any chance you could be running up against a file quota? Snakemake will store many small files in the .snakemake folder.

Comment: Hmm, don't think so. This happened on AWS with a large SSD which was is later used for the workflow.
I later realized that the debugging of the DAG is followed by the time stamp examination of all the files. Many of those files were on S3. This step could be taking longer that I would be willing to wait. Anyway, I chose to break down the workflow into smaller workflows (one wildcards value at a time) which made it a lot faster.